# Can't boot into Windows after dualbooting Ubuntu

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, 18.10

GRUB still shows Windows but it doesn't start.

I have tried using boot-repair but it gives me an error too. So I've created a [boot-info summary](http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/qZHx9kGQsj/).

What could be the problem, and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

The summary says
"No boot loader is installed in the MBR of /dev/sda."
If I was you, I would boot the Macrium Reflect recovery media, or Windows recovery media, or any other bootable disk that fixes Windows boot. After ascertaining that I can successfully boot into Windows, I would run the grub boot-repair a second time, from CD or flash drive. That should fix the Linux side of things, because the Windows repair tool will have deleted Grub. After that, you should be sorted.

EDIT: It was suggested to me by @karel that you use the free Linux tool Rescatux, instead of Macrium Reflect recovery media. Try that instead, because it will fix Windows bootloader without deleting grub.